# Why functors that preserve cokernels are right exact?

Tags: modules, exact-sequence

*"Let **$F$** be a functor from $A-$modules to $A-$modules that preserves **cokernels**. Then **$F$** take exact short sequences into right exact short sequences."*

I found a mistake in my proof. I also can't find it anywhere because everybody seems to find this too obvious.

***Here's my proof:*** Let $0 \rightarrow L \rightarrow^{\alpha} M \rightarrow^{\beta} N \rightarrow 0$ be a short exact sequence and let $F$ be a functor that preserves cokernels.

We want to show that $F(L) \rightarrow^{F(\alpha)} F(M) \rightarrow^{F(\beta)} F(N) \rightarrow 0$ is exact

Since $\beta$ is surjective, then $coker\beta = 0$. Then we have,

$0 = F(0) = F(coker \beta) = cokerF(\beta)$. So $F(\beta)$ is surjective.

Now we have to show that $ImF(\alpha) = KerF(\beta)$.

$ImF(\alpha) \subset KerF(\beta)$ is easy because $\beta \circ \alpha = 0 \Rightarrow F(\beta) \circ F(\alpha) = 0$

Since the original sequence is exact, we have $Im\alpha = Ker\beta$. Then,

$\frac{F(M)}{KerF(\beta)} = F(N) = F(\frac{M}{Ker\beta}) = F(\frac{M}{Im\alpha}) = F(coker\alpha) = cokerF(\alpha) = \frac{F(M)}{ImF(\alpha)} $

***My mistake:*** $ImF(\alpha) \subset KerF(\beta)$ and $\frac{F(M)}{KerF(\beta)} = \frac{F(M)}{ImF(\alpha)} \Rightarrow KerF(\beta) = ImF(\alpha)$.

I know this last claim is not true.

I realy appreciate any help whatsoever.

Comment: Share your proof. Perhaps people can help fix it.

Comment: That's it. Sorry about that. I really should have shared my work from the start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your argument is almost right. If you knew that $\ker{F(\beta)}$ contained ${\rm im}\, F(\alpha)$ you would be able to conclude that (why?).

Consider the epimorphism $L\stackrel{\alpha'}\to \ker\beta\to 0$. Then we know $\iota\alpha'=\alpha$ where $\iota$ is the inclusion $\ker\beta\to M$. By hypothesis $\rm coker\,\alpha'=0$ so that the map $F(\alpha'):FL\to F(\ker\beta)$  is an epimorphism.

But the image of $F(\alpha')$ is the same of that of $F(\alpha)$ so ${\rm im}\,F(\alpha)= F(\ker\beta)=F({\rm im}\,\alpha)$.

Thus means that ${\rm im}\,F(\alpha)=F({\rm im}\,\alpha)$ is contained in $\ker F(\beta)$, and now you argument goes through: if $A\subset B$ and $M/B=M/A$ then necessarily $A=B$.

Comment: I'm a bit confused by that last claim: if $A \subset B$ and $M/A = M/B$ then $A = B$. This may be true for equality but it is not for isomorphisms: Take $M = k[x1, x2,...xn,...], A = 0$ and $B = (x1)$, then $M/0$ is isomorphic to $k[x2,x3,...] = M/B$ assigning $x_i$ to $x_i+1$.

Comment: Yes, I am using equality, not isomorphism.

Comment: Oh, I just saw that everything is canonical. Thanks